# Autoincrement li tags generated by a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this function who parses an `xml` file:

```
<ul id="flussi">    
    <script type="text/javascript">
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("FLUSSI.xml") // Path to the XML file;
var M = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ROAD");
for (i=0;i<M.length;i++){

//document.write("<div id='id'>"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ID")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</div>");
document.write("<li>"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("NAME")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+ "</li>");
document.write("<li>"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SIM")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+ "</li>");
document.write("<li>"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("REAL")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+ "</li>");
document.write("<li>"+ xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DIFF")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"--"+"</li>");

}
 </script>
</ul>
```

That writes on an html file a list of values like these:

```
<li> Ponte_Nuovo_sx</li>
<li>87</li>
<li>72</li>
<li>15--</li>
```

Now I want to autoincrement the `li` tag, but still I try to find a solution.
In the case the `li` tags aren't generated by a function, and so if they are static, I can increment the `li` tag.

What I want to obtain is that (if it's possible):

```
<li id=1> Ponte_Nuovo_sx </li>
<ii id=2> 87 </li>
```

and so on.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate for those of us unfamiliar with the concept of incrementing tags? We may still be able to help.

Comment: Are you looking for an ordered list (`<ol><li>List item</li></ol>`)?

Comment: @MartinBean, i want to obtain from the javascript function autoincrementing '<li id=x>' tags, in order to edit some css properties of them :)

Comment: the less you manipulate the DOM the better it will be :) make it in a single `document.write` and store the `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(...)` values. Faster stronger! as for your auto increment you could do `document.write('<li id="li_'+i+'"> .....');`

Comment: Is a server-side language, like PHP, available?

Comment: ok that's a good solution @TecHunter i will try it :)

Comment: no @MartinBean in this case i don't use a server side language, it's a very simple HTML page :)

Comment: @AlessandroBocci you said it's for CSS then you should rely on class rather than IDs. see my solution. if you have a hundred of elements... that won't do it with 400 ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can't you do like this:

```
var count=0;
for (i=0;i<M.length;i++){

//document.write("<div id='id'>"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ID")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</div>");
document.write("<li id="+count+">"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("NAME")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+ "</li>");
count++;
document.write("<li id="+count+">"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SIM")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+ "</li>");
count++;
//and so on
}
```

Comment: Sorry Sir, how can i do if i want to add a name before "+count+" ? EDIT: solved, i had a problem on syntax :)

Answer (score 2):

```
// Have this run after it's been written to the document
$(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', ($(this).index() + 1));
    });
});
```

Note that this could probably and should be run through php, python or equivalent instead.

Otherwise you can simply handle an increasing value and given in Anubhab's answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i choose the solution from @Anubhab that in my case is more faster :)

Comment: but this is a better solution in general.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, that's what I meant :

**JS**

```
xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("FLUSSI.xml") // Path to the XML file;
var M = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ROAD");
var t_name = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("NAME");
var t_sim = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SIM");
var t_real = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("REAL");
var t_diff = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DIFF");


for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {

    //document.write("<div id='id'>"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ID")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</div>");
    document.write('<li class="name" id="name_' + i + '">' + t_name[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</li>' 
        + '<li class="sim" id="sim_' + i + '>' + t_sim[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</li>' 
        + '<li class="real" id="real_' + i + '>' + t_real[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</li>' 
        + '<li class="diff" id="diff_' + i + '>' + t_diff[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '--</li>');

}
```

**CSS**

```
li.name{

}
li.sim{

}
li.real{

}
li.diff{

}
li#name_1{

}
/** Only with CSS3 compliant browsers **/
li.name:nth-child(2n)
{
    /** Only pair child, works with numbers to to target single element but faster to use ID then. **/
}
```